# How to get RGB values based on illuminance (Lux) in Python?

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, rgb, graphical-programming

I am building an application using pygame/OpenGL where I can display the illuminance values (Unit : Lux) as RGB points. The Lux values are all numerical so I want them to display graphically in my application. I have searched for many papers and articles but there is no mention of using any standard scale for this. Is there any way this can be accomplished using Python ?

Comment: RGB usually gives a color not the illumination.

Comment: You cannot do it. sRGB (the most common RGB colour space) tell us that white is 1.0,1.0,1.0 (or 255, 255, 255). How many lux has a white it is indeterminate. It depends on monitor settings (and adaptation of monitor, common on smartphone), on your eye adaptation, etc. You need libraries which talk with hardware (not sure if they exist/reliable on most hardware), and colour doesn't depend on lux (remember: eye and brain adapt for brightness and colours). Note: graphical designer tend to have darker monitor then most of people.